# PHP is begin/start with multiple string use OR/|| operand

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get isBeginWith function combine with OR (||) operand, it works but i want a neat code for this problem. I'm trying to make regex but not really sure. I want to combine with if in_array but I'm really confused. Here is it my code

```
$isBeginCreate = substr($permission->name, 0, strlen('create_')) === 'create_';
$isBeginRead = substr($permission->name, 0, strlen('read_')) === 'read_';
$isBeginUpdate = substr($permission->name, 0, strlen('update_')) === 'update_';
$isBeginDelete = substr($permission->name, 0, strlen('delete_')) === 'delete_';
$isBeginCrud = $isBeginCreate || $isBeginRead || $isBeginUpdate || $isBeginDelete; 

if($isBeginCrud){
// here my codes
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what could be the possible values of $permission->name ?

Comment: The regexp is `/^(create|read|update|delete)_/`

Comment: `if (preg_match('/^(create|read|update|delete)_/', $permission->name))`

Comment: it can anything @svikramjeet

Comment: how about not begin/start with? @Barmar

Comment: `if (!preg_match(...))` will invert the test.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. I forgot

Comment: How to get string after create_ read_ update_ delete_? @Barmar

Comment: Use a capture group. `if (preg_match('/^(?:create|read|update|delete)_(.*)/', $permission->name, $match))` the part after will be in `$match[1]`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a tutorial on using regexp in PHP. This isn't a tutoring service, you can't ask us to feed you every step.